# wpdb insert working in one function, but not another

Tags: wpdb, oop

I have the following function:

```
function addToShortlist($propref) {

    global $wpdb;

    if (isset($_SESSION['shortlist'])) {

        $shortlist = new Namespace\Shortlist($_SESSION['shortlist']);
        $result = $shortlist->addProperty($propref);
    }
    elseif (empty($_SESSION['shortlist'])) {

        $list_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT MAX(list_id) FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_shrtlst");
        $new_list_id = ++$list_id;
        // Insert into database
        if ($wpdb->insert( 
            $wpdb->prefix . 'ch_shrtlst', 
            array( 
                'list_id' => $new_list_id,
                'property_id' => $propref,
                'time' => current_time('mysql')
            )
        )
        ) {
            $_SESSION['shortlist'] = $new_list_id;
            $result = new Namespace\Shortlist($_SESSION['shortlist']);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In the class, I have the following method

```
public function addProperty($propref) {

    global $wpdb;

    if ($wpdb->insert( 
            $wpdb->prefix . 'ch_shrtlst', 
            array( 
                'list_id' => $this->list_id, 
                'property_id' => $propref,
                'time' => current_time('mysql')
            )
        )
    ) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

When the session is set and the function calls the method on the object, the database query works perfectly, but for some reason, the query won't work directly from the function. I'm not getting any errors or anything, just nothing happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the code is skipping because the `elseif` condition is not fulfilled?

Comment: I thought that. If I remove the if statement altogether the code runs (albeit not in Safari). I've tried `elseif (!isset($_SESSION['shortlist']))` I can't see how else I can do it. The session variable is either there or not I would have thought.

Comment: This is driving me crazy. In firefox it works, but only if I refresh the page and in Safari, it won't work at all.

Comment: I ought to mention, if it's relevant that the function is run from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

This function was being made by an ajax call. The anchor link that made the call pointed to the same url. I changed the href to # and it now works perfectly.